# Should I change my accepted answer when a second answer comes up more comprehensive than the first?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

On the same day I have asked this question:

[How were bullets fired through the propeller in the Focke Wulf 190?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/31168/how-were-bullets-fired-through-the-propeller-in-the-focke-wulf-190)

I got an answer on the same day I posted. It was a good answer.. I accepted it.
Many other people liked it as well, since that answer got so far 47 up votes.

Couple of days after that, someone else posted another answer, even more comprehensive and specific than the first, and to the exact aircraft model that I was referring to in my question, the Focke Wulf 190, the answer even contains a link to further details in the design of the aircraft in question and brings up other details like the way they kept the ammo for the machine guns heated with the heat of the engine, etc.

Should I change the accepted answer?

There are penalties on doing that, and I don't want to pay.

Comment: not the machine guns, the ammo was heated! Marcello, I have enough points and do not mind the least that you keep the accepted answer. I only answered because I wanted to add my view to the page. You may vote as you like. BTW: If you decide to switch, the original answer will earn its author a gold badge. And thanks for the question, it was fun to research it!

Comment: @PeterKämpf I want to do the right thing, both here and in the skyes, whether I am on a Cessna 172 or Focke Wulf 190, I also enjoyed the question provided much more info that I could put together with google. I need to think of another one shortly..

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> there are penalties on doing that, and I don't want to pay.

There's no penalty for changing the accepted answer. Unaccepting an answer loses you the 2 rep points you gained for accepting it, but accepting the other answer will get you them back again.

The accepted answer should always be the one you think is the *best*: the most relevant, helpful, complete, informative, or whatever other criteria apply best for your question. If you think the accepted answer is not the best, it's up to you to fix that.

An unwillingness to change the accepted answer is a big factor in what Stack Overflow calls the "fastest gun in the west" problem: people write a half-assed answer to a novice question as quickly as possible, because novice questioners will usually accept whichever answer is first.

Comment: In addition, selecting an answer quickly (say before 24 hours) could stop answers from others, answers which may have provided additional good elements, and could have contributed to increase the overall quality.